# Custom bytes chunk size for file.openRead().pipe(client)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am uploading a file to a client.

```dart
    await file.openRead().pipe(client).then((value) {
      print("Uploading Done!");
    }, onError: (value){
      print("Uploading Done With Error!");
    });
```

Where `client` is a `Socket` object.
By default, the server sends 65536 bytes at a time. Can I somehow increase the count of bytes?

Comment: 65536 is the data size for integer data type , check your upload method

Comment: @Prashant what is "upload method"?
file.openRead().pipe(client) actually the whole code on the server side. Or do you mean the client side?

Comment: "Can I somehow increase the count of bytes?" no, it is hardcoded

Comment: btw what do expect if you increased the buffer, for example from 64k to 1M? I'm pretty sure it would not impact upload speed in any way

Comment: @pskink, why do you think so? 
I followed the following logic. The TCP socket is waiting for a delivery confirmation. As such, I'd rather send more data at a time than send in small chunks, as I'll be waiting for confirmation for each send. In addition, there are certain time costs for the data transfer itself. Am I missing something?

Comment: @pskink, you are right! It doesn't speed up loading. I increased the buffer size on the client side and it really increased the download speed a lot. I think the number of bytes to send is determined by the capabilities of the client.

Comment: Or is it just in my case since I use the Unreal app as a client.